# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, sqlite

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня при нажатии на кнопку - "сохранить данные" из заполненной формы в sqlite вылетает ошибка:

```
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     ... 11 more
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at ru.zloyel.manager_sutochnoy_arendy_1.Zaselenie.saveState(Zaselenie.java:576)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at ru.zloyel.manager_sutochnoy_arendy_1.Zaselenie.onClickSaveZas(Zaselenie.java:591)
03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     ... 14 more
```

Судя по логу, ошибка возникает где-то вот в этом месте кода:

```
private void saveState() {
        String kvartira = (String) spKvart.getSelectedItem();
        String client = (String) spContact.getSelectedItem();
        String date_start = etDateStart.getText().toString();
        String time_start = etTimeStart.getText().toString();
        String date_end = etDateEnd.getText().toString();
        String time_end = etTimeEnd.getText().toString();
        String zas_bron = tvInfo.getText().toString();
        String days = tvInfo2.getText().toString();

        if (rowId == null) {
            long id = zdb.createNewZas(kvartira, client, date_start,
                    time_start, date_end, time_end, zas_bron, days);
            if (id > 0) {
                rowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            zdb.updateZas(rowId, kvartira, client, date_start, time_start,
                    date_end, time_end, zas_bron, days);
        }
    }   
        public void onClickSaveZas(View v) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etDateStart.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(Zaselenie.this, "Дата заезда не введена",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                saveState();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно? где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Что у вас на 576 строке? У вас там переменная не определена...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет, обратите внимание на

> 03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150): Caused by: **java.lang.NullPointerException**
> 03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at ru.zloyel.manager_sutochnoy_arendy_1.Zaselenie.saveState(Zaselenie.java:576)
> 03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at ru.zloyel.manager_sutochnoy_arendy_1.Zaselenie.onClickSaveZas(Zaselenie.java:591)
> 03-11 19:15:54.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):

Предполагаю, что в методе saveState() null затесался